# Como contar número de registros em uma tabela?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela chama **`noticias`**, onde cada notícia tem um `id`. Também tenho uma tabela chamada **`comentarios`**, onde lá tem o `id` da notícia que o usuário comentou. Como posso contar os comentários para aquela notícia?

Comment: Mostre como está a estrutura de tabelas. Provavelmente o que você precisa é só de SQL para a contagem em si.

Comment: `select count(id_comentario) from comentarios where id_noticia = ?`

Comment: Eu fiz assim:  $contador = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM 10cms_noticias_resp WHERE id_noticia = id_noticia") or die(mysql_error());    . Para que eu possa puxar o número de comentários da notícia que eu tô o que eu faço?

Comment: @Kloves

Não seria melhor colocar o nome do campo como fk, já que é uma chave extrangeira?

Na verdade, este relacionamento é que uma notícia tem vários comentários. Logo o id de cada notícia vai para a chave extrangeira de cada comentário.

Parte da query:

WHERE fk_noticia = id_noticia") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer da seguinte forma, é bom adicionar um alias(nome) para a contagem assim fica fácil de lembrar o nome do campo no php.

```
$contador = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) as total FROM 10cms_noticias_resp 
                         WHERE id_noticia = id_noticia") or die(mysql_error());

$comentario = mysql_fetch_assoc($contador);
echo $comentario['total'];
```

Comment: Esse total é da função count?

Comment: `total` é nome da coluna retornada pela consulta, a sql mudou um pouco `SELECT count(id) as total` o as definiu o nome.@Kloves

Comment: Não aparece nada no echo.

Comment: faça um `print_r($comentario)` veja se aparece algo, @Kloves

Comment: Onde eu coloco o print_r?

Comment: depois do echo. @kloves

Comment: Apareceu: Array ( [total] => 1 ). Como posso colocar para aparecer só o 1?

Comment: é so fazer `echo $comentario['total'];`.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26246/discussion-between-rray-and-kloves).

Answer (score 1):

Uma simples consulta pela id, já resolve:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_comentarios FROM comentarios where id_noticia=:id
```